# Unit Testing JS - using JEST

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Beginner Level - Unit Testing

Here's the function

```
export function toHex(number) {
const nstr = number.toString(16);
 if (nstr.length % 2) {
 return `0${nstr}`;
 }
 return nstr;
```

Able to figure out if the function is true or not by running the following Unit testing code:

```
// testing new function 
describe('toHex', () => {   //mocking the method
test('Testing Function toHex ', () => { // declaring the method
  const str = 14 // initial value
  const actual = toHex(str) // calculate the value
  expect(actual).toMatchSnapshot(); // checking whether is true
})
});
```

Now how could I add different scenarios and make the following function to pass / Fail
Thanks

Comment: You should explain in more details what do you expect from your test, you're not "testing" for testing. You're testing to validate a correct behavior, what's the behavior you want to test ? You can try to phrase it like it to help you : "given [some initial state], when [something happens], then [I expect something]"

Comment: I understand it. Im working on it right now to make sure the function gets call.

Comment: @PierreCriulanscy function is getting called right ? How could I add a different scenario so ill make the function to  fail